# X3DOM Remove a clip plane

Tags: javascript, x3dom

I am working on the html 3D viewer X3DOM and especially on using "clip planes" as shown in this example:
https://examples.x3dom.org/clipPlane/clipplane.html

My question: How to remove an object created with javascript?

In this example, the object "ClipPlane" is created with this function:

```
function addClipPlane()
        {
            addMenu();
            clipPlanes.push( new ClipPlane(clipScope, scene, runtime) );
        }
```

I can't reach to obtain each ClipPlane element and to remove them. Do you know how should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to you question:

> How to remove an object created with javascript?

you need to clarify what object within which context you mean. For your particular example see my answer below.

Yes, you can. You would need to extend the example for a removing function. Within `clipplane.js` add:

```
this.Remove = function ( value )
{
    _scope.removeChild(_clipPlane);
    _proxyParent.removeChild(_proxyTransform);
};
```

You could call this like that:

```
var i = 1; // index to be removed
clipPlanes.splice(i, 1)[0].Remove();
```

But I rather advise you to write you own code. Because you might meet other limitations of the example code as well if you are going to use it on a real world aaplication.